# How can I use 'remove()' method with two or more while loops without ValueError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have a string of text 
`text = u"Hey, there, hope you are doing good??????  or maybe not?"` 
and a `token` version using `spacy`, I'm using spacy because I want to be able to use its other features like part of speech tagging, lemmatization and so on. The problem I'd love to solve is removing stop words like `['?',',',you']` from the token. The tokenized version of token is saved in `toks`

```
token = nlp(text)
toks = []
for t in token:
    toks.append(t.lower_)
```

I was thinking of using multiple `while loops` like this

```
 while "?" in token.text:
      toks.remove("?")
 while "," in token.text:
      toks.remove(",")
 while "you" in token.text:
      toks.remove("you")
```

but I keep getting `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` which is perfectly understandable, as it keeps removing until there is nothing to remove which thereby leads to an error.

However I found a way to handle the error using

```
while True:
    try:
        if '?' in tokens.text:
            toks.remove('?')
    except:
        try:
            if ',' in tokens.text:
                toks.remove(',')
        except:
            try:
                if 'you' in tokens.text:
                    toks.remove('you')
            except:
                break
```

I'm not getting the error any more, but I feel like there should be a better way to solve the problem without nested loops.  Can you suggest a cleaner way?

Comment: Why would `toks.remove("?")` have any effect on `tokens.text`? Why are you checking whether an item is in one data structure and then removing it from a different one?

Comment: There's a better function for removing substrings: [`str.replace`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm). Use it like this: `mystr.replace('substring', '')`

Comment: And what the heck does this have to do with JQuery?

Comment: sorry @user2357112 I didn't know that I tagged jquery. removed

Comment: @Jerfov2 I'm sorry I didn't state that toks is a list and not a string. `toks = []
for t in tokens:
    toks.append(t.lower_)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you just trying to get rid of certain substrings ("?", ",", and "you")?

Comment: I noticed that the question's getting negative feedback, is the context still obscure? it's a problem that I've been trying to solve for hours, it's not nice to give negative feedback without trying to help solve the problem.

Comment: @Jerfov2 yes I am

Comment: You should have a single block of code that recreates the central problem.  You should also have a clear problem statement.  At this point, the structure of the list isn't entirely clear -- try just setting that to an example list of strings, rather than deriving it from an external package.  Also, it's not clear whether you want to remove "you" from an element in the list, or remove the entire element.

Comment: @Prune Teju, I edited Prune's answer to get what you need (hopefully)

Comment: @Prune I appreciate your feedback, I recreated the central problem. hopefully I was being explicit this time around. @Jerfov2 close, but that's not what I need, I want to manipulate toks and not text, `text` is a `str` while `toks` is a `list`. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method, with the empty string as the new string.

```
for target in ['?', ',', 'you']:
    text = text.replace(target, '')
```

What this does is loop through items that need to be replaced and inserts empty strings every time it sees that string

Comment: toks is a list, list item has no attribute `replace`

Comment: Please post code that elicits the problem you cite.  Your given code doesn't define the variables before using them.  I'd be happy to test a solution in your context, once we have it.

Comment: I noticed that the question's getting negative feedback, is the context still obscure? it's a problem that I've been trying to solve for hours, it's not nice to give negative feedback without trying to help solve the problem.

Comment: That's a general comment on the question, and should go up there -- not under my non-working answer.

Comment: Thank you Prune and @Jerfov2 for your help.

Comment: @Tejumade If an answer helps you, make sure to upvote it and/or accept it (that goes for any question/answer) ;)

Comment: @Jerfov2 I tried but I got this :( `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score`

Comment: @Tejumade You can still accept the answer

Comment: You hit "accept" just *below* the up/down arrows.

Comment: @Prune: but why would the OP accept this answer which advises text replacement and not removal of items from a list (which OP made clear in the first comment)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want to exclude all tokens from a given set of tokens, it's easier to just  ignore them while creating the `toks` list:

```
from spacy.en import English

unwanted_tokens = {'?', ',', 'you'}

text = u"Hey, there, hope you are doing good??????  or maybe not?"
nlp = English()
tokens = nlp(text)
toks = []
for t in tokens:
    if t.lower_ not in unwanted_tokens:
        toks.append(t.lower_)

>>> toks
[u'hey', u'there', u'hope', u'are', u'doing', u'good', u' ', u'or', u'maybe', u'not']
```

The `for` loop could be replaced by a list comprehension:

```
toks = [t.lower_ for t in tokens if t.lower_ not in unwanted_tokens]
```

---

If, for reasons that you don't show in your question, you must remove the tokens *after* `toks` has been created, then you can just use a list comprehension:

```
toks = [t for t in toks if t not in unwanted_tokens]
```

Comment: This was all I needed, it worked the way I wanted it to. Thank you @mhawke.